# Как узнать кто вызвал функцию?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Есть свойство caller, но в typescript почему то не получается применить
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller

Делаю как то так

```
export class Shoot extends State {
    shoot(point: PIXI.Point, state: string) {
        console.log(this.shoot.caller);
        this.playerComponents.network.socket.emit('touche', point);
        this.playerComponents.changeState(this.playerComponents.states[state]);
    }
}
```

Изначальная задача понять из какого класса был вызван метод и перейти в предыдущее состояние, для этого просто передаю строкой имя класса.

Пример того как вызывается функция

```
export class Move extends State {

    timer: any;

    move(input: number) {
        clearTimeout(this.timer);
        this.playerComponents.network.socket.emit('Input', input);
        this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
            this.playerComponents.changeState(this.playerComponents.states.Idle);
        }, 500);
    }

    shoot(point: PIXI.Point) {
        this.playerComponents.network.socket.emit('Input', 0);
        this.playerComponents.changeState(this.playerComponents.states.Shoot);
        this.playerComponents.state.shoot(point,'Move');
    }
}


.....
 states: any = {
        'Idle' : new Idle(this),
        'Move' : new Move(this),
        'Shoot': new Shoot(this),
        'Build': new Build(this),
    };
.....
```

Минимальный пример

```
  this.playerComponents.state.shoot(point,'Move');
```

Comment: Попробуйте так `console.log((this.shoot as any).caller);`

Comment: стоит добавить пример того, как вызывается эта функция

Comment: попробуй упростить пример, чтобы он стал минимальным

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это работать не будет, потому что

> Uncaught TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them

```js
"use strict";
function f() { return f.caller }
function g() { return f() }
g()
```

Правильно делать так, чтобы это не требовалось.
Возможно, стоит глянуть паттерн Шаблонный метод.

Если caller нужен для какого-то логирования, то можно попытаться распарсить стек вызовов из `new Error().stack`

```js
"use strict";
function f() { return new Error().stack }
function g() { return f() }
console.log(g())
```

Comment: читаю шаблонный метод, может поможет тут, caller  я так понял не везде работает

Answer (score 1):

В общем нашел ответ 
оказывается если вывести в консоль arguments
просто вот так вот

```
  shoot(point: PIXI.Point, state: string) {
        console.log(arguments);
        this.playerComponents.network.socket.emit('touche', point);
        this.playerComponents.changeState(this.playerComponents.states[state]);
    }
```

То все становится очевидным дальше добираемся до caller
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280389/how-do-you-find-out-the-caller-function-in-javascript

Хотя думал что будет undefined, пока не проверил
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну ведь не работает... Смотрю в хроме.

Comment: @Qwertiy у меня работает в хроме

Comment: И что же работает? На скриншоте я вижу `(...)`, если на него нажать, то будет ошибка. Если только у тебя strict-режим не отключен.

Comment: @Qwertiy да ошибка, когда попытался добраться, но в целом было полезно задаться этим вопросом =)